# getjson - unable to read a local json file

Tags: javascript, jquery, getjson

Using this script:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    console.log("1");
    $.getJSON( "bares.js", function( json ) {
        console.log("2");
        console.log( "JSON Data: " + json.locations[1].nombre);
    });
    console.log("3");
</script>
```

I am not able to access to the JSON file that is  in the same directory.

bare.js is in the same remote directory of index.html. the jason is:

```
{"locations":[
      {"nombre":"name1","lat":"41.6504","long":"-0.879137"}, 
      {"nombre":"name2","lat":"41.6504","long":"-0.879137"}, 
      ....       
        ]
}
```

`console.log("2")` are not printed.

Comment: What does the Net tab in your browser's developer tools say? Does the console report any errors?

Comment: Define "local"? `http://localhost/` or `file://blah blah`?

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/jquery.getjson/ `Important: As of jQuery 1.4, if the JSON file contains a syntax error, the request will usually fail silently. ` also testing ajax requests from file:// (e.g. opening an html document in your browser from your desktop) won't work

Comment: Are you sure `bares.js` contains JSON and not, as the file ending suggests, JavaScript?

Comment: Like @FelixKling said, it appears you're using the wrong file extension: `.js` instead of `.json`.

Comment: I just edit adding the json file. It is in the same directory, on my remote server. Web console do not show the message inside getJSON function.

Comment: Share you json file...

Comment: first of all change the file extension to json and try to access the file directly from browser if its accessible or not.i think if you will change the extension it will work

Comment: http://myweb/bares.js is acesible

Comment: Just to be clear, the file extension doesn't matter. What matters is the contents of the file. And no, the link is not accessible.

Comment: Try this : $.getJSON( "filefoldername/bares.js", function( json ) {} Hope this will work for you :  $.getJSON( "myweb/bares.js", function( json ) {}

Comment: File contents looks correct. Is the path to the file correct? Read these articles to [learn](http://juliepagano.com/blog/2014/05/18/javascript-debugging-for-beginners) [how to](http://www.creativebloq.com/javascript/javascript-debugging-beginners-3122820) [**debug** JavaScript](https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/docs/javascript-debugging), so you can provider more useful context information (and help yourself).

Answer (score 0):

This code works for me:

in my project *JSON/samp.js*

```
{"locations":[
  {"nombre":"name1","lat":"41.6504","long":"-0.879137"}, 
  {"nombre":"name2","lat":"41.6504","long":"-0.879137"}]}
```

my code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        console.log("1");
        $.getJSON('JSON/samp.js', function (json) {
            console.log("2");
            console.log("JSON Data: " + json.locations[1].nombre);
        });
        console.log("3");
    });
</script>
```

Comment: So you are saying that there is nothing wrong with the OP's code? What's the point of writing an answer then? Should be a comment instead.